# Sum up the column using Access sql query

Tags: sql, ms-access-2010

I have a table like

```
     EID     PCNum

     1001     3.6
     1001     5
     1002     10
     1003     5
     1003     4
     1004     8
     1005     1.8
     1005     5.2
```

I'm trying to sum up PCNum if EID's are same. Eg: 1001=8.6

Result

```
     EID     PCNum

     1001     8.6
     1002     10
     1003     9
     1004     8
     1005     7
```

How do i specify in SQL query?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Very straightforward:

```
SELECT EID, SUM(PCNUM) FROM table1
GROUP BY EID;
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the query:

```
Select EID, SUM(PCNum) PCNUm from TableName Group By EID
```